# How to call a function that is inside the loop and has to stay there

Tags: javascript

I know it might be a lame question but I got stuck with the idea of how to get the value from the function that is inside the loop.
Can you guys just put some light on what should I do?

The code looks something like this :

```
  function radioCreator(){
  //creates radio button
  }

  function main(){
   for (i = 0; i < nQ; i++) {
      radioCreator("answerOption", "answer" + (i + 1));
      for (j = 0; j < nA; j++) {
      //here I got some more code 

           function finished(){
               for (i = 0; i < nQ; i++) {
                   for (j = 0; j < nA; j++) {
            if (document.getElementsByName("answer"+ (i + 1))[j].checked.value == true){
                goodAnswers ++;
                console.log(goodAnswers);
            } else {
                console.log("No good answers");
            }
                             }
                        }

                    }
                  }
             }
      }
      function getAnswers(){
      finished();
      console.log(goodAnswers);
      }
```

What I want to do is that after click of a button I want to execute **getAnswers()** function,
but it says that :

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: finished is not defined
```

which I get but I wonder : I want to get the goodAnswers variable value, how can I execute funcion **finished()** from outside the loop?

Comment: why you  have function inside the loop?

Comment: move **finished** function outside the **main** function

Comment: If I move it outside isn't it going to lose the i and j variable values?

Comment: You can pass the `nQ` and other variables needed as parameters to a function `finished` outside of the `function main()`

Comment: please add the other parts as well for a working example.

Comment: Ok I figure that out I've moved method outside the loop and passed pointers to the function.

I knew that was pretty simple but sometimes blackouts happen, anyways thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

try adding `this.finished = finished` to make `finished()` a public method

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the method outside the loop, and pass pointers to the function.

Comment: Uff I think that was sth I was looking for, in my defence I knew it, but I got complete blackout in my head 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

use some return object in `main` function
like this and call the `finished` function like this `main().finished()`

```
function radioCreator() {
//creates radio button
}

function main() {
for (i = 0; i < nQ; i++) {
  radioCreator("answerOption", "answer" + (i + 1));
  for (j = 0; j < nA; j++) {
    //here I got some more code 
return {
   finished : function() {
      for (i = 0; i < nQ; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nA; j++) {
          if (document.getElementsByName("answer" + (i + 1))[j].checked.value == true) {
            goodAnswers++;
            console.log(goodAnswers);
          } else {
            console.log("No good answers");
          }
        }
      }

    }
    }
  }
}
}

function getAnswers() {
main().finished();
console.log(goodAnswers);
}
```